# KEK (Key Encryption Key) o que é e como usar corretamente

Tags: criptografia, rsa

Estava a ler "Criptografia e Segurança: O guia oficial do RSA" porém fui limitado a algumas páginas (se alguem tiver o PDF deste por favor compartilhe!!) e entao me deparei com a KEK e nao pude ler mais..

O que é e como usa-la corretamente?

Com tudo que eu li é apenas uma chave que assegura a segurança da chave original, entretanto li também que passwords (senhas de usuário) nao é algo muito seguro de se usar pois é mais facil de quebrar e conseguir a chave original.. na parte que ele explicava isso nao consegui ler mais (estava lendo na prévia do google books)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **Key encryption key (KEK)**

É usada pela aplicação para proteger(criptografar/descriptografar) outras chaves`(e.g. TEK, TSK)`.

## **Um exemplo de uso**

Se você já usou as chaves TEK e TSK para proteger alguma coisa, como uma chave de sessão, as mesmas não devem ser armazenados em claro, mas criptografado com uma KEK. Além disso, a KEK não deve ser armazenada no mesmo local que as chaves de criptografia que está criptografando.

Na imagem abaixo uma chave de sessão protege os dados, e uma chave de criptografia chave (KEK) protege a chave de sessão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui](http://books.mcgraw-hill.com/downloads/products/007213139X/007213139X_ch03.pdf) tem um capitulo inteiro de um livro falando sobre isso. É muito bacana e fácil de entender :)

Exemplo código:

```
Código rodando no servidor 1:
public string Data(){
    AES objeto = new AES();
    objeto.key= getkey(EncryptedDEK);
    //descriptografa os valores
}

public string getkey(string EncryptedDEK){
  // conecta ao servidor 2 e obtem o DEK
  request(EncryptedDEK); 
}

Código rodando no servidor 2
public string request(string encryptedDEK){
    //verificamos a requisição
    //descriptografamos a DEK que foi criptografada com KEK
   // e então retornamos o DEK descriptografado
}
```

Comment: explicou mas nao aprofundou nos pontos, vou aguardar mais respotas, obg!!

Comment: Foi o máximo que consegui entender. Espero que tenham mais respostas também.

Comment: Basicamente é usada para isso, acho que se quiser se aprofundar ainda mais no assunto vai ter que ler algum artigo científico ou alguma coisa do tipo :)

Comment: A KEK não deve ser armazenada em hipótese alguma. A única coisa que se armazena, é o salt gerado.